# Hyper-v Internal Network - No internet Access

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, rras

I am trying to setup a virtual network in Hyper-V to give my VM internet access.  I have created an internal and external network, and I see both connections inside of the Network Connections manager.  However, when I click on the status of "internal" it says IPv4 - No Internet Access.

I see the internal network inside of Routing and Remote Access and it has assigned itself a gateway of 169.254.141.95.  How do I get the internal network to recognize the internet connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a link local address.  Either your DHCP server is unreachable, our you need to manually configure the IP address settings for the network.  The settings must be configured on the virtual NIC, not the the physical one (after it has been configured in Hyper-V network manager).

Comment: I do have the IP address configured on the Virtual External Network.  The internet is working fine on the host machine, I'm just not sure why the internal network is unable to connect to the network.  I'm assuming that's why my host machines aren't able to connect either.